# Understanding how $\sum_{k=0}^n 3^k2^{n-k} , n \geq 1 $ has been simplified

Tags: summation, geometric-series

> I want to understand how this sum has been simplified for $n \ge 1$:
>
> $$
> \begin{split}
> \sum_{k=0}^n 3^k2^{n-k}
>  &= 2^n\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^k \\
>  &= 2^n\frac{1-\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{3}{2}} \\
>  &=-2^{n+1} \left(1-\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{n+1}\right) \\
>  &= 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}
> \end{split}
> $$

I think that in the first step we have $2^n$ and $2^{-k}$ which is why we can write $2^n$ before the sum and $2^{-k} = \frac{1}{2^k}$. Then $3^k \cdot 2^{-k}$ would give $\frac{3^k}{2^k} = \big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^k$. Is that correct?

In the second step the getometric series has been used. But what happened in the last 2 steps?

Comment: Try doing the simplification of the last two steps on your own and you will see why it is so *elementary*.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit That's what I tried before asking

Comment: What is $ 1- \dfrac 32$ ?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit $-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: And since that is in denominator , it will become $-2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to see what's happening if you use *variables* $a$ and $b$ instead of the *numbers* $2$ and $3$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^na^kb^{n-k}
&=b^n\sum_{k=0}^n(a/b)^k\\
&=b^n{1-(a/b)^{n+1}\over1-(a/b)}\\
&=b^{n+1}{1-(a/b)^{n+1}\over b-a}\\
&={b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}\over b-a}
\end{align}$$

The crucial step here (after invoking the formula for the sum of a geometric series) involves multiplying numerator and denominator by $b$ so as which changes the denominator from $1-(a/b)$ to $b-a$. If we now substitute $a=3$ and $b=2$, we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n3^k2^{n-k}={2^{n+1}-3^{n-1}\over2-3}={2^{n+1}-3^{n+1}\over-1}=3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why you get $b-a$ after increasing $n$ by $1$? (Before it was $1-(a/b)$)

Comment: When you multiply numerator and denominator of $b^n\over1-(a/b)$, by $b$, you get $b^{n+1}$ in the numerator and $b-a$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, thanks :)